# Two different JQueryUI themes on one page

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui, cdn

I'm using the Google CDN to load my JQuery file. However, I'd like to have my master page use a separate theme to my content page. Is this possible when using the CDN? I'm using ASP.NET. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master/content page actually forms a single HTML page when delivered to the client.  To make it work, you'd need to duplicate all of the selectors for the jQuery UI CSS file and extend them to make them specific to your content page -- so that they are more specific than the standard jQuery UI selectors and thus are applied instead of the standard jQuery UI selectors for just the contents.  Then you'd load both CSS files -- the standard jQuery UI CSS and your more-specific-selector-based UI CSS.  You may still run into some conflicts, especially with elements that are placed relative to the page rather than a specific element -- drag/drop elements using cloning, dialogs, etc.